# How do I run a .py file quickly if that file pulls functions from other .py files

Tags: python, spyder

**Background:**

I have three .py files that I use on Spyder every morning:

1. functions.py file contains a functions I use
2. calculation.py uses the functions to get the data and do some calculations on it
3. morning.py uses the data to produce a chart

In calculation.py I have the line to import my functions

```
%run '/Users/mak/Dropbox/Python/fed nlp/functions.py'
```

Then I run through around 100 lines of code in calculation.py to use these functions to pull data, clean it, and produce a nice table.

Finally, I open morning.py which uses this table to produce a nice chart for me.

**Problem:**

In order to speed up my daily process, I tried inserting this line into morning.py:

```
%run '/Users/mak/Dropbox/Python/fed nlp/calculation.py'
```

However I get the message:

```
%run '/Users/mak/Dropbox/Python/fed nlp/calculation.py'
  File "/Users/mak/Dropbox/Python/fed nlp/calculation.py", line 2
    %run '/Users/mak/Dropbox/Python/fed nlp/functions.py'
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I guess you cannot do a 'run' command via another 'run' command...

Any idea for how I can speed up my daily process?

Comment: ```%run ...``` is a spyder command and isn't a valid statement in python.

Comment: Why don't you import your function and calculations with the `import` statement? Why are you using this `%run` command?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it's going to work but you could try to put these three files in the same directory and after to write in the "functions" file and "calculation" file:

```
if "_name_" == "_main_":
    pass
```

After that you have to import these two files in the "morning" file using import:

```
import functions.py
import calculation.py
```

In this way you can do everything inside the "morning" file.

I apologize if this does not solve your problem

Comment: It is `if __name__ == '__main__': ` , instead of comparing two string.

Comment: if "__name__" == "__main__":  ,it's not just a comparison, it allows you to do many things, one of which is to import your .py file into another .py file in a very simple way

Comment: Correct, the statement is to execute the code in the If statement block only if the file is the main file that is runnend. When that file is imported in a other script it won't execute the code (while the imported file is not the main file).  But the name should not be in 
quotation marks because __name__ is a special variable.